# How can other Windows computers of the same network display what I do on my computer and hear my voice?

Tags: windows-7, networking, display, network-shares

I have a local network with several computer with Windows 7 installed. As a tutor, I want to show what I do on my computer to my students via their own Windows-7 computers (connected to the network of course).

I also want to let them hear my voice.

Is it possible to do this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are many web conferencing programs that will do this.

If you want a simple whiteboard, you can use this [website](https://awwapp.com/).

If you need to run programs (such as powerpoint) while other interact, you can use a [web conferencing program](http://www.anymeeting.com/).